# Updating columns if not null

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table 'Contacts' with a bunch of rows and columns that looks a bit like this:

```
ID |FirstName|LastName|Addr1|Addr2      |Phone   |...|
1  |Anna     |Johnson |123  |Fake street|12345678|...|
2  |Bob      |Smith   |234  |Foo Ave    |23456789|...|
```

Now Anna has moved and I want to update her address. My system outputs a row with the Contacts rowtype where the PK and updated columns have a value, everything else is null.

```
declare
 update_row Contacts%rowtype;
begin
 update_row := (1,null,null,987,Bar Street,null,null);
```

What I want to do now is keep the original row of Contacts and just update the values that are not null in update_row.
What I essentially want to do is this:

```
if update_row.FirstName is not null then Contacts.FirstName := update_row.FirstName;
if update_row.LastName is not null then Contacts.LastName := update_row.LastName;
if update_row.Addr1 is not null then Contacts.Addr1 := update_row.Addr1;
if update_row.Addr2 is not null then Contacts.Addr2 := update_row.Addr2;
...
```

or something to that extent but without having to explicitly check every single column value. 
Is there a solution that looks something like this?:

```
merge update_row into Contacts where update_row is not null and ID = 1
```

Comment: It might help to show us some sample data, in the form of a table.

Answer (score 2):

You could write a query that checks each input field and only replaces if a non-null value is given.

The following would work for Oracle, with the `NVL` function (in mysql, use `COALESCE`, and so on).

```
UPDATE CONTACTS
SET
    FIRST_NAME = NVL(?, FIRST_NAME),
    LAST_NAME  = NVL(?, LAST_NAME),
    ADDR1      = NVL(?, ADDR1),
    ADDR2      = NVL(?, ADDR2),
    PHONE      = NVL(?, PHONE)
WHERE ID = ?
```

Comment: Thank you :) But there a simpler solution to do all columns at once? In my actual table there are 46 columns and writing them each out is rather tedious. If there is nothing simpler I will go for your solution.

Comment: Hmm not that I can't think of.. At some point you have to be explicit about which column need to be updated and how...

Comment: I just thought that if I have everything on the same rowtype then all the values that should be updated are in the right place and I don't need to be explicit. Guess I was wrong.

Comment: @twedervang - if you don't want to write every column in your code, then write code that will write the UPDATE statement for you! This is a tame form of dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a concept how you can achieve it with package in a dynamic way.

```
CREATE TABLE contact (
  id      NUMBER,
  cust_id NUMBER,
  line1   VARCHAR2(100),
  line2   VARCHAR2(100)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE pkg_test IS

  /*
  * Variables for contact table.
  */
  gv_contact1 contact%ROWTYPE;
  gv_contact2 contact%ROWTYPE;

  /* Do overwrite for Contact table
   * pi_contact1.ColumnName is overwitten when pi_contact2.ColumnName IS NOT NULL 
   *
   * @param pi_contact1     Contact record which is overwritten
   * @param pi_contact2     Contact record from wich data are copied
   */
  FUNCTION overwriteContactIfNull(
    pi_contact1 contact%ROWTYPE,
    pi_contact2 contact%ROWTYPE
  )
  RETURN contact%ROWTYPE;

END pkg_test;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pkg_test IS

  /* List of columns in a table
   *
   * @param pi_tableName     Table name
   */
  FUNCTION columns_(
      pi_tableName       VARCHAR2
  )
  RETURN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
  AS
    lv_ColumNames SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
  begin
    SELECT CAST (
             MULTISET 
                  (
                    SELECT c.column_name
                      FROM user_tab_columns c
                     WHERE c.table_name = pi_tableName
                  ) AS SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST
                )
      INTO lv_ColumNames
      FROM dual;

    RETURN lv_ColumNames;
  END columns_;

  /* Do overwirte for a specific table
   * gv_#TableName1.ColumnName is overwitten when gv_#TableName2.ColumnName IS NOT NULL 
   *
   * @param pi_tableName     Table name
   */
  PROCEDURE overwriteIfNull(
    pi_tableName    VARCHAR2
  )
  AS
    lc_bodyTemplate CONSTANT CLOB :=
    'BEGIN'                                                                            || CHR(10) ||
    '  IF pkg_test.gv_#TableName2.#ColumnName IS NOT NULL THEN'                        || CHR(10) ||
    '    pkg_test.gv_#TableName1.#ColumnName := pkg_test.gv_#TableName2.#ColumnName; ' || CHR(10) ||
    '  END IF;'                                                                        || CHR(10) ||
    'END;';

    lv_ColumNames SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;

    lv_body CLOB;
  BEGIN

    lv_ColumNames := columns_(pi_tableName => 'CONTACT');

    FOR i IN 1..lv_ColumNames.COUNT
    LOOP
      lv_body := lc_bodyTemplate;
      lv_body := REPLACE(lv_body, '#TableName' , pi_tableName);
      lv_body := REPLACE(lv_body, '#ColumnName', lv_ColumNames(i));
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE lv_body;
    END LOOP;

  END overwriteIfNull;


  /* Do overwrite for Contact table
   * pi_contact1.ColumnName is overwitten when pi_contact2.ColumnName IS NOT NULL 
   *
   * @param pi_contact1     Contact record which is overwritten
   * @param pi_contact2     Contact record from wich data are copied
   */
  FUNCTION overwriteContactIfNull(
    pi_contact1 contact%ROWTYPE,
    pi_contact2 contact%ROWTYPE
  )
  RETURN contact%ROWTYPE
  AS
  BEGIN
    gv_contact1 := pi_contact1;
    gv_contact2 := pi_contact2;

    overwriteIfNull(pi_tableName => 'CONTACT');

    RETURN gv_contact1;
  END overwriteContactIfNull;

END pkg_test;
/
```

And this is example of call

```
DECLARE
  lv_contact1 contact%ROWTYPE;
  lv_contact2 contact%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN

  lv_contact1.line1 := 'Line1';
  lv_contact1.line1 := 'Line2';

  lv_contact2.line2 := 'NewLine2';

  lv_contact1 := pkg_test.overwriteContactIfNull(
                     pi_contact1 => lv_contact1,
                     pi_contact2 => lv_contact2
                 );

  dbms_output.put_line('lv_contact1.line1:' || lv_contact1.line1);
  dbms_output.put_line('lv_contact1.line2:' || lv_contact1.line2);
END;
/
```